# I cannot install ufw on Debian 8

Tags: debian, ufw

I just installed fresh Debian 8 and when I try to install `ufw` it will return:

```
# apt-get install ufw
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ufw is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ufw' has no installation candidate
```

Here is my:`/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
```

Same thing will happen if I try to install clamav.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sources.list` only contains the security repositories; you need the main repositories too

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
```

Add those two lines, run `apt-get update` and you'll be able to install `ufw`, `clamav` etc.